# Получение двух «свежайших» значений в новые столбцы результата

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Пардон, несколько затрудняюсь с формулировкой более понятного заголовка, суть затруднения см. ниже:
Есть представление(view) на основе таблиц неких задач, вкратце такого вида

```
TABLE VW_Tasks(
ID NUMBER  NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,       --идентификатор, первичный ключ
MELT_NUMBER VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) NOT NULL, -- № задачи
LADLE_NUM NUMBER(38)                    -- № агрегата
)
```

для каждой задачи есть несколько анализов водорода (взятых в произвольное время) в отдельной таблице вида

```
TABLE HYDROGEN(
ID NUMBER  NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,  --идентификатор, первичный ключ
MEASURE_NO NUMBER(3, 0) NOT NULL,        -- № измерения по порядку
HEAT VARCHAR2(8 BYTE) NOT NULL,                     -- № задачи
VALUE NUMBER(10, 3) NOT NULL,                       -- значение
TIME_RECIVED TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL  -- время получения анализа
)
```

Связанные между собой по № задачи `VW_Tasks.MELT_NUMBER=Hydrogen.HEAT`
(они немного разного размера по *бизнес-требованиям*  :(  в следствии чего не стоит на них строить внешний ключ, да и не могу я менять структуру таблиц; хранимые в них строковые значения на самом деле совпадают)

Пытаюсь получить результирующее представление, где для каждой задачи в 2 отдельных столбцах будут 2 последние ("свежайшие" по времени `TIME_RECIVED`) результаты анализов, следующим запросом:

```
SELECT T."ID", T."MELT_NUMBER", T."LADLE_NUM",  H1."H_last1", H2."H_last2"
FROM  VW_Tasks T  
LEFT JOIN ( 
  SELECT PH_last2.HEAT, PH_last2.VALUE "H_last1"
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM HYDROGEN PH
    WHERE PH.HEAT = T.MELT_NUMBER  --'815804'
    ORDER BY PH.TIME_RECIVED DESC
    FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY) PH_last2
  WHERE rownum=1
  ) H1   ON H1.HEAT = T.MELT_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN  (
  SELECT PH_last2.HEAT, PH_last2.VALUE "H_last2"
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM HYDROGEN PH
    WHERE PH.HEAT = T.MELT_NUMBER   --'815804'
    ORDER BY PH.TIME_RECIVED DESC
    FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY) PH_last2
  WHERE rownum=2
  ) H2   ON H2.HEAT = T.MELT_NUMBER;
```

Ожидаемо, эта корявость не работает -- в строках вложенных подзапросов `WHERE PH.HEAT = T.MELT_NUMBER` не признаёт `T.MELT_NUMBER`:

> ORA-00904: "T"."MELT_NUMBER": недопустимый идентификатор

но прекрасно срабатывает если для теста вместо `T.MELT_NUMBER` вручную указывать строку `'815804'`, существующую в полях обоих таблиц.

Подскажите, как бы лучше это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда нужно сколько-то значений вывести в строку, я лично предпочитаю `PIVOT`:

```
select *
  from (select *
          from (select T."ID", T."MELT_NUMBER", T."LADLE_NUM", PH.VALUE,
                       row_number() over (partition by T.MELT_NUMBER order by PH.TIME_RECIVED DESC) rn
                  from VW_Tasks T
                       join HYDROGEN PH on PH.HEAT = T.MELT_NUMBER)
         where rn <= 2)
 pivot (max(VALUE) as "H_last" for rn in ('1' as "1", '2' as "2"))
```

Тут все просто: сначала джойним таблицы, потом нумеруем результаты по времени (столбец `rn`), потом выбираем последние 2 значения (`where rn <= 2`), потом пивотом разворачиваем в столбцы.
Плюс этого подхода в том, что если понадобится вывести в столбцы последние 3, 5, 10 и т. д. значений, изменения вносятся элементарно.

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая, что для каждой строки выбирается по одному значению из каждого подзапроса, то можно непосредственно выбирать значения в списке выборки, без join-ов.

Только нужно принять во внимание, что значение [`ROWNUM`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255) рассчитывается только для строк, для которых выполняются все условия `WHERE` и до сортировки, соответственно условие `rownum=2` работать не будет:

```
SELECT T.ID,
       T.MELT_NUMBER,
       T.LADLE_NUM,
       (select t.value
            (SELECT PH_last1.VALUE, rownum as rn
                  FROM (SELECT ph.value
                          FROM HYDROGEN PH
                         WHERE PH.HEAT = T.MELT_NUMBER 
                         ORDER BY PH.TIME_RECIVED DESC FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY) PH_last1) t
         WHERE t.rn = 1) "H_last1",
       (select t.value
            (SELECT PH_last2.VALUE, rownum as rn
                  FROM (SELECT ph.value
                          FROM HYDROGEN PH
                         WHERE PH.HEAT = T.MELT_NUMBER 
                         ORDER BY PH.TIME_RECIVED DESC FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY) PH_last2) t
         WHERE t.rn = 2) "H_last2"
  FROM VW_Tasks T
```

Аналогичного результата можно добиться одним `JOIN` и аналитической функцией [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions170.htm#SQLRF06100):

```
select results.id,
       results.melt_number,
       results.ladle_num,
       --выбираем значения с номером 1
       max(decode(results.rn, 1, results.value, null)) "H_last1",
       --и значения с номером 2
       max(decode(results.rn, 2, results.value, null)) "H_last2"
  from (select t.id,
               t.melt_number,
               t.ladle_num,
               h.value,
               --номер по порядку с учетом номера теста
               row_number() over(partition by h.heat order by h.time_recived desc) as rn
          from vw_tasks t
          left join hydrogen h
            on t.melt_number = h.heat) results            
 where results.rn <= 2
 group by results.id, results.melt_number, results.ladle_num
```

Comment: не то, чтобы я не любил "простые" ответы с подвохом, заставляющие думать :) но иногда хочется уточнить, насколько сознательно внесена ошибка -- в вашем варианте `SELECT ph.value, rownum as rn   FROM HYDROGEN PH   WHERE PH.HEAT = T.MELT_NUMBER` возвращённый `rownum` будет для исходной табл. "как есть", а не для результата по условию -- чтобы это заработало потребовалось эту строку и её проверку `WHERE rn=1` сдвинуть соответственно выше по уровням вложения запросов, дописав ещё третий `SELECT`

Comment: @Alias подвоха тут никакого не было, просто я напутал. Приношу свои извинения! Хотя бы второй вариант должен работать.